# How I can read variables from csv in python

Tags: python, csv, variables

for example the variables in the csv are:

```
 a│b │
 5│12│
```

And i want parse the value of a in the csv to a variable and print the value + 5

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Have you tried searching for how to read a csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a` will always be in the first column, you can reference it by the row index `0`:

```
import csv
# assuming file is named 'csvfile.csv' in the current directory
with open('csvfile.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    # read the csv file and specify the delimiter 
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="|")
    #skip the header row
    next(csvreader)
    # for every data row in the file, add 5 to the number in the 
    # first column and print the result 
    for row in csvreader:
        value_of_a = row[0]
        print(float(value_of_a) + 5)
```